# Ant fileset includes no classes

Tags: ant

I have a folder `sources` with a subfolder `be` under it. Next fileset should select all *.cls files under the `be` folder, recursively! (so also .cls files in subfolders of the `be` folder):

```
<fileset dir="${basedir}/sources">
    <include name="be/**/*.cls" />
</fileset>
```

Apparently ant doesn't select a single file...

If I change it to

```
<fileset dir="${basedir}/sources/be">
    <include name="**/*.cls" />
</fileset>
```

Ant selects all of the .cls files.

What's the difference between the two snippets?

Folder structure:

- sources

  - be

    - dirA

      - dirB

        - .cls files
      - dirC

        - .cls files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both copy the files, just in different ways.

Notice how in the "be" directory root is included in the first copy:

```
├── build.xml
├── sources
│   └── be
│       └── dirA
│           ├── dirB
│           │   ├── file1.cls
│           │   └── file2.cls
│           └── dirC
│               └── file3.cls
└── target
    ├── copy1
    │   └── be
    │       └── dirA
    │           ├── dirB
    │           │   ├── file1.cls
    │           │   └── file2.cls
    │           └── dirC
    │               └── file3.cls
    └── copy2
        └── dirA
            ├── dirB
            │   ├── file1.cls
            │   └── file2.cls
            └── dirC
                └── file3.cls
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="copy">

  <property name="src.dir"   location="sources"/>
  <property name="build.dir" location="target"/>

  <target name="copy" depends="copy1,copy2">
  </target>

  <target name="copy1">
    <copy todir="${build.dir}/copy1">
      <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
        <include name="be/**/*.cls" />
      </fileset>
    </copy>
  </target>

  <target name="copy2">
    <copy todir="${build.dir}/copy2">
      <fileset dir="${src.dir}/be">
        <include name="**/*.cls" />
      </fileset>
    </copy>
  </target>

  <target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
  </target>

</project>
```